# Eshell -- how to use authinfo for login credentials

Tags: eshell

Tramp with dired-mode can use the `authinfo` file to automatically login.  This avoids setting up keys in the `.ssh` directory and also on the remote server.

**Q**:  How can I modify the behavior of `eshell` to access the `authinfo` file to automatically login to a remote server.

[CAVEAT:  I do not want to piggy-back by opening a Tramp `dired-mode` buffer and then launching `eshell` -- i.e., I want `eshell` to access the `authinfo` file without the help of `dired-mode`.]

[I am aware of the option to use a utility called `sshpass`, but I'd like to use the `authinfo` file.]

Comment: Here is a link to an answer that I wrote up on redit for `shell-mode`:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6jwjhw/is_a_sequence_like_this_possible_in_emacs/djl4jvp/?st=j4j9hhg5&sh=334d64f4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All operations in eshell dedicated for a remote server are mapped to Tramp. If you are in a local directory, you could switch to a remote directory like this:

```
Welcome to the Emacs shell

~ $ cd /sudo::
/sudo:root@detlef:/root $
```

This will ask you for the password via Tramp, meaning `authinfo`. What exactly does not work for you?

Comment: I would like to type at a command prompt in a local directory (e.g., on my home computer):  `ssh username@ip-address -p 2222` and login to the remote server (e.g., in cyberspace) without being prompted for a password, such that `eshell` accesses the `authinfo` file for the password if it can find one -- if no password is found, then prompt me.

Comment: That's not supported, AFAIK. But why do you need this? Tramp functionality is available in eshell. Try the following commands in your eshell prompt: `cd /ssh:username@ip-address#2222:` and then `hostname`. You will see, that the `hostname` command has been executed on the remote host.

Comment: Thank you -- I'll give this a try in a day or so and I'll look at `eshell/cd` to see what makes it tick in terms of activating the functions that use the `authinfo` file (e.g., `tramp-read-password`).  I previously created a custom `eshell-send-input` function that can accept a fourth argument in the form of a string such as `"ls -la /"`.  My ultimate goal will be to create a function that will launch `eshell` (or find it if it's already open) and login to the remote server (under the hood of `eshell`) and then update the buffer with a new prompt for the remote once logged in using `authinfo`.

Comment: If you want to make it programmatically, it is sufficient to bind `default-directory` to the remote server. Something like `(let ((default-directory "/ssh:username@ip-address#2222")) <call your eshell functions>)` . Tramp comes in, and does the password ping-pong with you.

Comment: Wow!  That little tip is an Emacs life-changing event for me.  To avoid `Host name must not match method "ssh"`, I added the path on the remote server (shared account):  `(let ((default-directory "/ssh:username@ip-address#2222:/home/username")) (eshell))`  Thank you.  :)

Comment: I found a previous answer of yours elsewhere and see that the missing ingredient on your previous comment was a colon at the end, so the revised example would be:  `(let ((default-directory "/ssh:username@ip-address#2222:")) <call your eshell functions>)`